# Column based on combinations of values in two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I want to create a new column based on values of two other columns. Dummy dataframe

```
freqg <- data.frame(mat=c(1,2),flank=c(1,2,3,4))
```

This seems rather simple

```
freqg$condition[freqg$mat==1 & freqg$flank==1] <- "LK"
freqg$condition[freqg$mat==1 & freqg$flank==2] <- "FQ"
```

but the combinations of the values in two columns are large and I also need to replicate this for many other dataframes. Can the combinations can be customized encoded in single line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Create a combination-condition data frame*** (`comb_df`) and **`left_join` on your original data frame** using dplyr or `merge` from base R.

Use `expand.grid` to create the combinations you want. Something like:

```
comb_df <- data.frame(expand.grid(mat = 1:2, flank = 1:2), 
                      condition = c("LK", NA, "FQ", NA)

comb_df
#  mat flank condition
#1   1     1        LK
#2   2     1      <NA>
#3   1     2        FQ
#4   2     2      <NA>

freqg %>% dplyr::left_join(comb_df)            # OR merge(freqg, comb_df, all.x= T)
#  mat flank condition
#1   1     1        LK
#2   2     2      <NA>
#3   1     3      <NA>
#4   2     4      <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

you might prefer the dplyr equivalent

```
freqg %>%
  mutate(condition = case_when(
    mat %in% 1 & flank %in% 1 ~ "LK",
    mat %in% 1 & flank %in% 2 ~ "FQ"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand.grid` for all combinations, then create another column which I called `cc`, then use `merge` to combine this dataframe with the `condition dataframe` which I called `cond_df`

```
> freqg=expand.grid(mat=c(1,2),flank=c(1,2,3,4))
> freqg
  mat flank
1   1     1
2   2     1
3   1     2
4   2     2
5   1     3
6   2     3
7   1     4
8   2     4
> cond_df=data.frame(cc=c(11,12),condition=c("LK","FQ"))
> cond_df
  cc condition
1 11        LK
2 12        FQ
> merge(cbind(freqg,cc=do.call(paste0,freqg)),cond_df,all=T)
  cc mat flank condition
1 11   1     1        LK
2 12   1     2        FQ
3 13   1     3      <NA>
4 14   1     4      <NA>
5 21   2     1      <NA>
6 22   2     2      <NA>
7 23   2     3      <NA>
8 24   2     4      <NA>
```